# Rotate and Scale with auto-layout in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, scale, autolayout

This is an issue I have been having for a good while now. With the new iOS6 and auto-layout my gesture recognizer "game" is no longer working.

I have created an app using storyboards and on one of the *tabs* there is a little game application where the user must scale, rotate, and pan an image on top of another image within 5 pixels, 5% size, and 5 degrees. The issue I am having with auto-layout is that when rotate and scaling the game image the image "jumps" back to it's *starting position* and rotates awkwardly and not around the center.

My methods for handling the *rotate* and *scale* gestures are below.

**Rotate**

```
//rotation gesture recognizer response
- (void)respondToRotateGesture:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(gesture.view.transform, gesture.rotation);
    }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) [self didWin]; //not important for question
    gesture.rotation = 0;
}
```

**Pinch**

```
//pinch gesture recognizer
- (void)respondToPinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(image.transform, gesture.scale, gesture.scale);
    }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) [self didWin]; //not important for question
    gesture.scale = 1;
}
```

I do realize that the easiest solution would be to turn off *auto-layout* but that causes issues in the rest of the storyboard because in storyboards you cannot turn of auto-layout for one component but you must turn it off for the entire storyboard.

Can anyone advise me what to do? I have read that this is a major issue and some are calling it a "bug" with the new auto-layout.

I am just having problems with this and I need some help

If anyone has any suggestions or can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

-Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way around this was to create the image programmatically using the following code to remove auto-layout. Since you cannot set `image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` if you add the image into the view using IB due to the apple "bug" with auto-layout. Because you will get an error saying, "`Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`"

So you need to do this programmatically because IB adds constraints and you don't want any.

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gorilla_red.png"];
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:image];
```